# Is it possible to create a custom mail storage for MS Outlook 2007?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, vsto, outlook-2007

I know that Outlook stores all mail in a .PST file.

Is it possible to create a custom storage engine for outlook 2007?

I would like to have the functionality similar to 'Personal folders', but have a new node of folders where everything is stored in a SQL Server database.

Is Outlook extensible enough to allow swapping the internal storage, while leaving the UI intact (so I don't have to recreate it from scratch)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find this article interesting - [Outlook to SQL](http://www.outlookwise.com/OutlookWise/Outlook_SQL_Synchronization/01_Outlook_SQL_Synchronization.htm)

It is about syncing Exchange Server with SQL database. Unfortunately I am not aware how you can completely put away the "Outlook storage engine"

Answer (score 0):

You could synchronise your email with SQL fairly easily, but replacing the storage engine and removing the PST sounds tricky.
At a guess I'd say you will at least in part need to use MAPI and CDO to do this.
I don't think the new storage engine part of the Outlook OM will do it.

Is there a specific reason why syncing the data into SQL is insufficient for your needs?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the question is no longer relevant.

Comment: perhaps for yourself, however SO is a resource for anyone on the internet so the answer may have value for another programmer.